# validation from input if character is alphabetical

Tags: python

Hi I am new to programming and I am trying to write a code that will gather information from the input and determine if it is a valid alphabet.

I previously asked this question before but the answers given just didn't work so I am asking the question again. Please help

```
words = []
word = input('Character: ')
while word:
 if word not in words:
  words.append(word)
 word = input('Character: ')
print(''.join(words),'is a a valid alphabetical string.')
```

suppose I choose three letters then the output of my code then pressed enter
on the fourth, 
the code will be:

```
Character:a
Character:b
Character:c
Character:
abc is a valid alphabetical string.
```

I want to add to this code so that when I type in a character that is not
from the alphabet the code will do something like this.

```
Character:a
Character:b
Character:c
Character:4
4 is not in the alphabet.
```

This is exactly how I want my output to be.

[image]

Comment: I have showed what I tried

Comment: Added an answer to your previous question. This one should be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the string class I think you will find it has some variables you would find useful.

```
from string import letters
word = raw_input("Character: ")
words = []
while word and word in letters:
  if word not in words:
    words.append(word)
  word = raw_input('Character: ')
```

I don't have python on this computer but I think that you will find this chunk of code works.  Also, the string class has a several other variables you might find useful including digits, punctuation, printable etc

Comment: Where would I put this in my code

Comment: buddy, this pretty much matches your code exactly.  You should be able to figure out where to put this.  I think I left out the print statement.  That's all.

Comment: Your question was how to validate that characters are letters, not how to write the entire problem for you.  I've given you an answer to your question.  You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: the code doesnt work. You cant import name letters

Comment: perhaps you should post what version of python you are using.  It works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `string.isalpha()` function to find whether the input is alphabetic or not.

```
>>> 'a'.isalpha()
True       <-- as 'a' is alphabet
>>> 'A'.isalpha()
True       <-- as 'A' is also alphabet
>>> ''.isalpha()
False      <-- empty string
>>> '1'.isalpha()
False      <-- number
-------------------------
>>> 'ab'.isalpha()
True       <-- False, since 'ab' is alphabetic string

# NOTE: If you want to restrict user to enter only one char at time,
# you may add additional condition to check len(my_input) == 1
>>> len('ab') == 1 and 'ab'.isalpha()
False
```

In order to get the input from user, you can do:

- Using `raw_input`:

  `x = raw_input()  # Value of x will always be string`
- Using `input`

  `x = input()  # Value depends on the type of value`

  `x = str(x) if x else None  # Convert to str type. In case of enter with value set as None`

Comment: I have tried isalpha, you have to input as string

Comment: `raw_input()` return everything as string

Comment: my program says error raw-input not defined

Comment: It is not `raw-input instead `raw_input`. Note the `_`

Comment: I know that. It still says that

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Updated the answer using `input` as well as `raw_input`